# PHP form upload and image display

Tags: php, forms, upload

I have the index.php page with the form.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p class="select">Select image to upload:</p>
    <p><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit"></p>
</form>
```

This posts to upload.php which uploads the file to the directory /upload/

```
<?php
$target_dir = "upload/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != "pdf" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG, PDF and GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

I was then hoping to display the latest file on another page. Is this possible? Or do I need a database solution?

Comment: Use the mime type provided by `getimagesize` instead of relying on the filename. The filename can be manipulated by the user. Also pdfs aren't images. :-)

Comment: *"I was then hoping to display the latest file on another page."* - Sure, you can make use of `filemtime()`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Comment: Thank you @CharlotteDunois and Fred for the help and thank you for referencing me to the other post containing a similar issue. I have added the following so that I can specify the folder that the files are stored in.

'code'<?php
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator('/upload/');

$mtime = -1;
$file;
foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {
    if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getMTime() > $mtime) {
            $file = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            $mtime = $fileinfo->getMTime();
        }
    }
}
?>'code'

However, it's not working and i am stuck again.

Thank you,

Phil

Comment: After playing around, i wonder if this better describes what i am trying to do...

`code`
<?php
$LastMod = filemtime("/upload/.");
?>

<img src="<?php echo $LastMod; ?>" alt="" width="928px" height="400px" />
`code`